# Testing if a String is a cover string for a list of strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm, for-loop, arraylist

I am a beginner at coding so apologize if mistakes i have made are fairly obvious. 
Basically, i am trying to create an algorithm that will test if a given string is a cover-string for a list of strings. A string is a cover string for a list of strings if it contains the characters from each string from left to right order within it. For example a cover string for "house" and "hotel" would be "ahogjutsel", and an example of a non cover-string would be "ahogjsutel".

I have tried to create an algorithm with the intention of going through each individual word in the list of Strings and testing to see if it appears in a left to right order in the cover string by testing for index values. When running my code i get a "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError".

Any help into why i am getting this error or how to improve my code would be very helpful and appreciated.

```
public class StringProcessing {

public static ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
public static int size = stringList.size();
public static String list1 = "cat";
public static String list2 = "dog";
public static String list3 = "bird";

public static String coverString;
public static int coverSize = coverString.length();

//Algorithm to iterate through each word in stringList and test if it appears in the cover string
//by testing index values.
public static boolean isCover(String coverString){
    boolean isCover = false;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j<coverSize; j++){              

        if (coverString.indexOf(stringList.get(i).charAt(j)) < coverString.indexOf(stringList.get(i).charAt(j+1))){
            return true;
        }
        }
    }
return isCover;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    stringList.add(list1);
    stringList.add(list2);
    stringList.add(list3);

    StringProcessing.isCover("cdbaoird");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem :

```
public static int coverSize = coverString.length();
```

It throws a `NullPointerException`, since it's evaluated when the class is initialized (hence the `ExceptionInInitializerError`) and `coverString` is null.

Since you are not using the static `coverString` variable (you are using a local variable having the same name), I suggest you remove both of these lines :

```
public static String coverString;
public static int coverSize = coverString.length();
```

and instead of using `coverSize` in your `isCover` method, I suggest you replace it with `coverString.length()`.

EDIT :

Here's another problem :

```
public static int size = stringList.size();
```

This variable is initialized when `stringList` is still empty, which means you outer for loop is never executed, since `size` is 0.

I suggest you don't initialize these static variables when they are declared. Or even better, remove those static variables and use local variable instead, which you can initialize when you need them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, after updating these lines and entering strings that should produce a true value, my algorithm is still only outputting false however. I am unsure if my for-loop is set up to always produce a false output.